# Find modulus and argument

Tags: complex-numbers

The complex numbers $p$ and $q$ are such that :
 $|p| = 2,$  $\arg(p) = \pi/3$  $|q| = 7,$  and $\arg (q) = -\pi/4.$

Find the modulus and argument of $(p/q) ^5 $

I found that: $p = 1 + i \sqrt{3}$ and
 $q = (7 \sqrt{2} ) /2) - (7 \sqrt{2} ) /2)i.$

Comment: If you write $p$ and $q$ in polar form, you'll have a much easier time of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|\frac {p}{q}|=\frac {|p|}{|q|} $$
$$=\frac {2}{7} $$
$$|\frac {p}{q}|^5=\frac {2^5}{7^5} $$
$$arg (\frac {p}{q})=arg (p)-arg (q) $$
$$=\frac {\pi}{3}-\frac {-\pi}{4} $$
$$=\frac {7\pi}{12} $$

$$arg ((\frac {p}{q})^5)=5arg (\frac {p}{q}) $$
$$=\frac {35\pi}{12}=\frac {11\pi}{12} $$

Answer (score 1):

$p=2cis\frac{\pi}{3}$  and $q=7cis\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$.
Thus, $$\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^5=\frac{32}{7^5}cis5\left(\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\frac{32}{16807}\left(-\cos\frac{\pi}{12}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{12}\right).$$
Id est, $\left|\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^5\right|=\frac{32}{16807}$ and $\arg\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^5=\frac{11\pi}{12}$.